# Click on headerview in uitableview in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a `UITableView` with a header view. The header view is displaying a date, and I'd like that when people click on that date it shows a `UIDatePicker` so they can change the date.

I have no idea how to trigger the function to show the picker when people click on the header view.

Comment: You have the code for the date picker, you're just not sure how to trigger it?

Comment: I don't have the code yet but I first want to know how to trigger it. What function to use when people click on the headerview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard handling provided by the table view to detect users touching the header view. You can do it yourself by adding a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your header view and supplying it with the appropriate selector for the method which shows your picker.